# What's the difference between RDBMS and NoSQL in nature?

Tags: mongodb, rdbms, nosql

I don't know if this topic has been discussed or not. If yes, please point me there.

I mean the **REAL** difference, from the perspective of design philosophy. Someone's said that RDBMS is like automatic transmission vehicle, and NoSQL is like manual transmission vehicle. RDBMS is more like a black box, but NoSQL gives you more control on the way to organize data and thus the computation complexity of a query is predictable.

However, as we see, MongoDB is moving to provide similar query interface as RDBMS. Will RDBMS and NoSQL go to the same destination via different path?

Answer (score 0):

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/madgreek/nosql-vs-rdbms-apples-and-oranges-37713

This will give you a good understanding.

"Extremely large datasets are often event based transactions that occur in chronological order. Examples are weblogs, shopping transactions, manufacturing data from assembly line devices, scientific data collections, etc. These types of data accumulate in large numbers every second and can take a RDBMS with all of its overhead to its knees. But for OLTP processing, nothing beats the combination of data quality and performance of a well designed RDBMS."

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, strictly philosophically, it's the difference between empty file open in Notepad and a template table in Excel.